# Can a computer that uses EFI/UEFI rather than BIOS run a real mode OS?

Tags: bios, uefi, ms-dos

Title says it all: could I get away with installing a real mode OS such as MS-DOS on a EFI-based computer? I understand that EFI-based computers still use "BIOS emulation" for compatibility reasons, but would that emulation let me get away with installing and running a real mode operating system?

Unfortunately, I don't have an EFI machine readily available so I can't test this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the "BIOS emulation" aka "Compatibility support module" is present, then **it *has to* start in real mode because that's what all BIOS-format bootloaders expect** (even if many of them immediately upgrade to protected mode). Hence the 'compatibility' in its name.

(This of course only applies when booting from the MBR boot sector. All .efi format bootloaders always use the UEFI runtime.)